# Finding top 5 region and within region find top 5 customer by their price. (HIVE)

Tags: hadoop, hive

We have one requirement where we want to find top N region by their price sum and then find top N customers for each of the region.

Sample Data.

```
REGION_NAME,CUSTOMER_NAME,PRICE

RG1,Customer1,100
RG1,Customer2,200
RG1,Customer3,100
RG2,Customer4,100
RG2,Customer5,200
RG2,Customer6,400
RG3,Customer7,100
RG3,Customer8,200
RG3,Customer9,500
RG3,Customer9,200
```

Assume we want Top 2 region and Top 2 customer within each region by summing the price

Region_name,Region_sum,Customer_name,Customer_price (Sum)

```
 RG3,1000,Customer9,700 (Sum of customer price)
 RG3,1000,Customer8,200
 RG2,700,Customer6,400
 RG2,700,customer5,200
```

How to write HIVE query for this? We are not able to think how to write this using HIVE. We may have to write MapReduce or PIG?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in Hive using analytics functions and a self-join:

```
select regions_ranked.region_name, regions_ranked.region_sum, customers_ranked.customer_name, customers_ranked.customer_sum from
(
  select region_name, customer_name, customer_sum, rank() over (partition by region_name order by customer_sum desc) as customer_rank from (
    select region_name, customer_name, sum(price) as customer_sum
    from foo group by region_name, customer_name
  ) customers_sum
) customers_ranked
join
(
  select region_name, region_sum, rank() over (order by region_sum desc) as region_rank from (
    select region_name, sum(price) as region_sum
    from foo group by region_name
  ) regions_sum
) regions_ranked
on customers_ranked.region_name = regions_ranked.region_name
where region_rank <= 2 and customer_rank <= 2;
```

This gives the exact output that you were looking for, although out of order. You can tack on an "order by" clause at the very end if you want that.

Comment: It works but can you give explaination how it is done . It will help me and other who are trying to write some what complex queries.